# What is the data column name for showing website conversion of facebook ad report stats?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I can retrieve facebook report stats value by specifying data column names like "impressions", "clicks", "ctr" etc. as below. However I cannot find the data colum name for the number of website conversion.

Would you let me know how to retrieve the number of website conversions?

```
curl -G
data_columns=["adgroup_id","impressions","clicks"]
https://graph.facebook.com/<API_VERSION>/act_<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/reportstats
```

Answer (score 0):

Website conversions are tracked in the ad's tracking or conversion spec and are considered 'actions' that take place and are tracked against the ad.

The [`actions_*` columns](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/adreportstats/v2.2#action-columns) (specified in the `data_columns` parameter) contain information about the conversions that occured, including website conversions
You can group the output by action type using `&actions_group_by=['action_type']`

You can also add a filter if you want only website conversions, by adding a filter like this:

`&filters=[{ field: 'action_type', type:'in', value: ['offsite_conversion'] }]`